# Unable to install libxmljs on windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, libxml-js

I have the following softwares installed on my machine
Windows 10 (64 bit)
Node 4.2.6 (64 bit)
Visual Studio 2013

i am trying to install node package "libxmljs" using the following command

```
npm install libxmljs
```

but im getting the following error

```
libxml.lib(parser.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol snprintf
```

Here is the complete stacktrace

```
    Creating library C:\src\mysourcecode\node_modules\libxmljs\build\Release\xmljs.lib and object C:\src\mysourcecode\node_modules\libxmljs\build\Release\xmljs.exp
    libxml.lib(parser.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol snprintf [C:\src\mysourcecode\node_modules\libxmljs\build\xmljs.vcxproj]
    C:\src\mysourcecode\node_modules\libxmljs\build\Release\xmljs.node : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals [C:\src\mysourcecode\node_modules\libxmljs\build\xmljs.vcxproj]
    gyp ERR! build error
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23)
    gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
    gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10586
    gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
    gyp ERR! cwd C:\src\mysourcecode\node_modules\libxmljs
    gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.6
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
    gyp ERR! not ok
    npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
    npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "libxmljs"
    npm ERR! node v4.2.6
    npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

    npm ERR! libxmljs@0.17.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Failed at the libxmljs@0.17.1 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
    npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the libxmljs package,
    npm ERR! not with npm itself.
    npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
    npm ERR! You can get their info via:
    npm ERR!     npm owner ls libxmljs
    npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     C:\src\mysourcecode\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: This seems to be a recently introduced bug. Look at the issues tab on their github: https://github.com/polotek/libxmljs/issues

Since it's a bug I'd suggest perhaps closing this question.

Comment: @JohnO'Mahoney Thank.  Created issue on github https://github.com/polotek/libxmljs/issues/392